# Disable GDrive UI integration (temporarily)

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

Is it possible to disable Google Drive UI integration, for our new Google Webstore App?

Our web app uses the Google Drive API scope for managing users' documents, but we don't yet support Google Drive UI integration (i.e. we don't have a page which can take in a document ID and show appropriate content. The user would have to navigate from the home page instead). The app has been rejected from the GAM on this basis, and Google directed us here for technical support.

I have seen the following in the UI:

- In the 'Apps Marketplace SDK' settings, the checkbox for 'Google Drive SDK' is checked & disabled here *(project ID replaced with XXXXX)*: https://console.developers.google.com/project/XXXXX/apiui/apiview/appsmarket_component/googleapps_sdk.
- In the 'Drive SDK' settings, I cannot find a setting to disable Google Drive UI integration here *(project ID replaced with XXXXX)*: https://console.developers.google.com/project/XXXXX/apiui/apiview/drive/drive_sdk

We do hope to integrate with the Google Drive UI in the future. In the meantime we would like our new app to be available to our customers, for installation by their domain administrators.

Is there a known way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to disable the UI integration from the Developer Console.

In the Drive API's "Drive UI Integration" tab, find the "Creating files" checkbox and make sure it is unchecked. Also remove any MIME types you specified. You may want to uncheck any of the other checkboxes below "Creating files" that you may have checked.  Save those changes.

In the GAM SDK settings, you can uncheck the "Drive extension" box and save. That should disassociate your GAM app from being a Drive app as well.